# Two instances of the same table in the document

Tags: automation, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

In LibreOffice writer I have a table on which I perform some small calculations.

How can I have an instance of the same table on another page in the same document (automatically updated)?

(e.g. print a copy of the same page with some minor changes)

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to save the table in a separate document and link it using OLE. This way, you can use the full power of LibreOffice / OpenOffice Calc when working with your table.

To implement it, do the following:

1. **Create the Calc spreadsheet**, save  and close it (you can still modify it later, even from within writer);
2. In Writer, at each place where the table (Calc sheet) should appear, **insert (link) the calc sheet as an OLE object**:

   - Menu `Insert` -> `Object` -> `OLE Object...`;
   - Make sure to select "`Create from file`" and "`Link to file`":
     [image: OLE1]
   - In the `File` text box, enter the Path to the Calc sheet, or use the <kbd>Search...</kbd> button to select it, and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.
3. To **edit the Calc sheet**, you can:

   - either open the linked Calc file in Calc,
   - or select and double-click the object in Writer,
   - or right-click on the object and select `Edit` from the context menu in Writer.
4. To **update other instances** of the Calc sheet after editing it, just select Menu `Tools` -> `Update` -> `Update all`.